# How to access the processed result content in ArangoDB's Pregel when executing the LinearRank algorithm?

Tags: arangodb, pregel

The field in the resulting nodes seem to be stored in a format that I can't query using the web console, Python, or even Java. The content appears to be represented as a string (non-representable type double). I'm unsure if it's stored in VelocyPack binary format, but I'm unable to access the content.

ArangoDB Community 3.11

I can't query using the web console, Python, or even Java.